# How to reverse Delphi's TTrackbar.Orientation values?

Tags: delphi, vcl, win32gui, trackbar

When a `TTrackbar.Orientation` property is set to `trVertical`, the `Min` value is on top and the `Max` is on the bottom:

[image: trackbar showing position values on top and bottom]

How can I invert the `Min`/`Max` positions? If I would like to use a TrackBar in vertical orientation for a Volume control for audio output, for instance, I would need the `Min` on the bottom and the `Max` on the top.

Comment: Use subtraction.....

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't show the tooltip which moves with the thumb, I'd display the current volume in a piece of text that did not change position. That seems like better UX to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do that. But you could reverse the min-max value by code:

```
volume := (trackbar.Max - trackBar.Position) + trackBar.Min;
```

---

Regarding the presentation of the ToolTip value, @Victoria kindly provides a solution that intercepts the `TTN_NEEDTEXT` windows message, and corrects the text output:

```
uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

type
  TTrackBar = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTrackBar)
  private
    procedure WMNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify); message WM_NOTIFY;
  end;

implementation

procedure TTrackBar.WMNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify);
begin
  if Msg.NMHdr.code = TTN_NEEDTEXTW then
  begin
    PToolTipTextW(Msg.NMHdr)^.hInst := 0;
    PToolTipTextW(Msg.NMHdr)^.lpszText := 
      PChar('Position: ' + IntToStr((Max - Position) + Min));
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's what actually what I'm doing right now but this workaround do not solve the problem at all. The Tooltip that shows the actual value continue inverted. Sadly right now I got access only to the Delphi Starter Edition (so I can't dig throught the component's source).

Comment: @Poyo, that tooltip if built-in the Windows control. The control itself doesn't seem to have the capability of flip. For that tooltip you can handle the `TTN_NEEDTEXT` message notification and modify its text from there. Just for start something [like this](https://pastebin.com/QJH1zDj0) for Unicode.

Comment: Kind of a shame that you wait until after this answer has been written before adding the missing information